# how to fire event on canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i would like to fire click or keypress event on  element.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<canvas class="box-shadow" id="canvas" width="640" height="640"></canvas>
</div>
```

i have done like this:

```
$(".wrapper").click();
```

this is not working.

How to fire event from jquery/javascript. (i can't change this html file.)

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/DTRwF/1/

Comment: Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: @Anton that is custom event i guess.

Comment: Question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to programatically "fire" an event:

```
$('.wrapper').click(function(){
    alert("testing");
});

// will result in the click event handler being called
$(".wrapper").trigger("click");
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MYrWd/)

Answer (score -1):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');    
canvas.addEventListener("click", doSth, false);

function doSth() {
    // do anything you want here;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you are asking for but may be this is something close :

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PBcBc/

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', function() {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: i dont want to listen "click" event..i would like to fire event

Comment: do you want to fire an event on document ready or a simple mouse hover? you must have planned to execute the "click" event on some condition right ?